# Add to Flatlist from anoter screen

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-props

What I'm trying to do here is basically logging a workout by selecting exercises I did. All available exercises could be selected from an "Exercise Explorer" screen.

[image: Logging Screen]
[image: Exercise Explorer screen]

In the images provided above, I could click on the + button in the training logger screen, it would bring me to the exercise explorer screen, where i could select one or multiple exercises and then there would be a button to click add or something.

Here's the code I have so far
Logging Screen

```
const LoggerScreen: React.FC<HomeProps> = ({ navigation }) => {
  var today = new Date().toDateString()
  const [data, setData] = useState<string>('');

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>{today}</Text>

      <Text>X Exercises</Text>

      <Button title='Add' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Explorer')} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default LoggerScreen
```

Explorer Screen

```
const Item = ({ item, onPress }) => (
  <Pressable onPress={onPress}>
    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
  </Pressable>
);

const ExplorerScreen: React.FC<HomeProps> = ({navigation}) => {
  
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <Item item={item} onPress={() => selectExercise(item.name)} />
    )
  }

  const selectExercise = (name:string) => {
    console.log(name)
    /* selectExercises(name); */
    navigation.navigate('Logger', {name});
  } 
  
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Explorer Screen</Text>

      <FlatList data={DATA} renderItem={renderItem} keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ExplorerScreen
```

So far, here are the resources I looked into to try to solve my problem, but it didn't work.

[Passing Data from child to parent component](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/passing-data-from-child-to-parent-component-in-typescript-react-92ab6d03ceb1)

[Pass flatlist items to another screens flatlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67283299/how-to-pass-flatlist-items-to-another-screens-flatlist)

[Child to parent functional components in reactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63431820/passing-data-child-to-parent-functional-components-in-reactjs)

1. Feel free to ignore typings. I'm currently learning React-Native and I'm slowly learning how to type my screens, navigations and everything.
2. I know I could use a global store, but my goal here would probably be to select exercises and return it directly into the logging screen state, and then only when the log is saved, it would be saved to a global store for each workout day. What do you think?
3. If I use navigate() from the explorer screen(child) to the training logger(parent), does it pop from the stack? Because that is what the [react-navigation documentation recommends](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigating/#going-back).
4. This is more of a future question about my application but, the explorer screen could be called from the logging screen to select exercises, but is also a repository of exercise where to can explore and learn about exercises (without selection options). How could i achieve this? Typing my screen with optional props and using conditional rendering? (I haven't looked into this yet, feel free to ignore)

Thank you very much for you time. And don't hesitate if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function selectExercice, I would update the database with the selected exercice and then redirect to the "Logger" page.

```
const selectExercise = (name:string) => {
   /* 
    A call or function that update the database with the selected exercice
    - You will probably have to pass the user as parameter to the function

    database.addExercice(name)
   */

   navigation.navigate('Logger');
}
```

Once the user has been redirected to the "Logger" page, I would use the [useEffect hook](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage) to fetch the exercices from the database and then render them with the map function like so:

```
const LoggerScreen: React.FC<HomeProps> = ({ navigation }) => {
  var today = new Date().toDateString()
  const [data, setData] = useState<string>('');

  useEffect(() => {
    //Get exercices from database
    database.getExercices().then((exercices) => {
      exercices.forEach((exercice) => {
        data.push(exercice);
      });
      /*
        The next line of code is not a necessity but it will help 
        performance. I encourage you to look this up.
      */
      Promise.all(data)
      setData(data)
    })
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });


  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
      <Text>{today}</Text>
      {
       data.map((exercice, key) => <Text>{exercice.name}</Text>)
      }

      <Button title='Add' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Explorer')}/>
    </View>
  );
};

export default LoggerScreen
```

This code has not been tested so errors may occur.

If you are not using a database. This solution will not fit your need but I strongly suggest that you use one.

In case you don't want to use a database, I recommend you to use the localStorage of the phone with a library like [AsyncStorage](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage). Using strictly the navigation history to store the exercices will not prevent the user from losing all his data if I quit the app.

Comment: Thank you so much Olivier!
Your answer is well structured, very complete and it helped me quite a lot! Thanks again! :)